# why file image is null in controller

Tags: laravel

when i submit form with file image  but file is null in controller.
here is form

```
<form action="{{url('company',$cdetail->id)}}" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     @csrf
     <input type="text" name="Name" value="{{$cdetail->name}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
     <br>
     <input type="text" name="Email" value="{{$cdetail->email}}" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
     <br>
     <input type="file" name="Logo"  class="form-control" placeholder="Logo">
     <br>
     <div class="modal-footer">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

and controller

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
   dd($request);
}
```

Comment: you should be using `POST` for this not `GET`

Answer (score 2):

According to documentation

The [HTTP POST method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST) sends data to the server. The type of the body of the request is indicated by the Content-Type header. The content type is selected by putting the adequate string in the enctype attribute of the  element.

and The [HTTP GET method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET) requests a representation of the specified resource. Requests using GET should only retrieve data.

Change

```
<form action="{{url('company',$cdetail->id)}}" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

TO

```
 <form action="{{url('company',$cdetail->id)}}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```